# Search page MVC routing (hidden action, no slashes, like SO)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want my searches like those in Stack Overflow (i.e. no action, no slashes):

```
mydomain.com/search                        --> goes to a general search page  
mydomain.com/search?type=1&q=search+text   --> goes to actual search results
```

My routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(  
  "SearchResults",  
  "Search/{*searchType}",      --> what goes here???  
  new { action = "Results" }  
);  
routes.MapRoute(  
  "SearchIndex",  
  "Search",  
  new { action = "Index" }  
);
```

My SearchController has these actions:

```
public ActionResult Index() { ... }  
public ActionResult Results(int searchType, string searchText) { ... }
```

The search results route does not work. I don't want to use the ".../..." approach that everyone seems to be using, because a search query is not a resource, so I want the data in a query string as I've indicated, without slashes--exactly like SO does.

TIA!Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two routes because you're providing search parameters as query string. Just have one search route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search",
    "Search",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Search" }
);
```

Then write this controller action

```
public ActionResult Search(int? type, string q)
{
    var defaultType = type.HasValue ? type.Value : 1;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
    {
        // perform search
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```

The body of this method greatly depends on the search condition whether you require both parameters when you search for stuff or just `q` and you have some default for `type`. Remember that page indexing can be done just the same way.

### Using strong type parameters (validation wise)

You could of course create a class that could be validated, but property names should reflect that of the query string. So you'd either have a class:

```
public class SearchTerms
{
    public int? type { get; set; }
    public string q { get; set; }
}
```

And use the same request with equally named query variables as you do now, or have a clean class and adjust your request:

```
public class SearchTerms
{
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
}

http://domain.com/Search?Type=1&Query=search+text
```

Comment: Works nicely in this manner. But if I use a model binder though (to bind a model that wraps "type" and "q") what do I specify for the route?

Comment: Nothing to specify in route, but in _Action_ you have to be careful about _Model_ validation. you can include or exclude _Model_ properties using `Bind` attribute

Comment: Route would stay the same, but query variable names would have to adjust to class property names. Lemme write some code.